# File types and ways that can infect Android devices with malware

Tags: malware, android

From what sources can an Android device be infected with malware?
What various file types, executable or non executable, can infect an Android device with malware?

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to remember about malware on Android is that you have to actually install the malicious app. Malware writers will use increasingly clever techniques to try and trick you into doing just that.

- **So, can an android app on Google Play be fake or malicious?**

Yes, it might be.

- **What can an Android malware/virus do?**

The vast majority of malware on Android is focused on stealing your information, which is obviously a major concern. Perhaps the worst case scenario at the moment is malware that sends SMS messages to premium rate numbers.

There are apps that clone legitimate apps to fool you into downloading them and apps that are malware free when you first install them, but download malware through the update system.

The most common Android malicious apps will do at least one of the following:

- Collect and send GPS coordinates, contact lists, e-mail addresses
  etc. to third parties
- Send SMSs to premium-rate numbers
- Subscribe infected phones to premium services
- Record phone conversations and send them to attackers
- Etc.

If they have the permission they will use it! (ex: If you give access to your camera ... they can use your camera)

- **Is there anything more dangerous then that?**

Yes. Your phone is a mini computer and you install things on it. If one of your installed application has vulnerabilities (ex: Remote Code Execution) maybe a hacker can hack your device if it is on the same network or it can send a specific targeted payload.

Answer (score 1):

> From what sources can an Android device be infected with malware?

The most common problem is to install apps from outside the google play store, i.e. third party app stores or just by downloading an APK. Often these apps claim to be hacked versions of commercial apps, the next version of a popular game or similar. Installation of such apps requires manual interaction by the user but in many cases this is no problem because the greed to get some free or cool stuff often impacts clear thinking.

But given the amount of phones out there which run an outdated and insecure android version you also see drive by downloads which infect the device simply when you browse the net, i.e. [silent drive by downloads](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3060912/malvertising-attack-silently-infects-old-android-devices-with-ransomware.html). Such drive by downloads can not only be found at the dark sides of the internet but increasingly at common sites which got either hacked or where the malware is served through advertisement networks ([malvertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertising)).

> What various file types, executable or non executable, can infect an Android device with malware?

Installation packages are APK files and these usually require manual confirmation by the user before install.  But with the help of exploits (see above) it is possible to silently install apps. The most well known exploitable bug is [Stagefright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagefright_(bug)) and this one is [actively exploited](http://thehackernews.com/2015/07/how-to-hack-android-phone.html).